# How many DOM elements can a browser handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, svg

I'm using svg with over a 6000 elements I want to increase add a few thousand DOM element in my current webpage. But I noticed that whenever I'm trying to manipulate like zooming in/out (using plug-ins) my page is getting very slow to response.
I would like to know the maximum capacity of a browser to handle DOM does it depends on machine configuration?

Comment: Yes, it depends entirely on the client machine - ie. how much memory is available. I would imagine that the browser imposes no limits until a OutOfMemoryException occurs.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i feel you just answered it.

Comment: There is no specified number for DOM element for any browser so you can load as much DOM as you want. Zooming in/out getting slow because browser adjust all of your DOMs and readjust all.

Comment: You can add as many DOM elements you want. But when manipulating all those elements, things will get slow and unresponsive, since it uses the CPU. You might be able to use CSS 3D transforms scale to mimic a page zoom in and out. CSS 3D transforms can tap into the GPU (hardware acceleration) and pushs elements on a new rendering layer giving smoother performance. Manipulating DOM elements the browser needs to re-calculate, re-layout, re-paint and re-composite on every frame (RAF). Whereas canvas performs better at manipulating thousands of elements at once. See http://csstriggers.com/

Answer (score 2):

There is no such standard. The smallest number is the best. And it depends from browser to browser. Older browsers are not that good in rendering complex dom structures. Even simple events such as "mouseover" and "mouseout" may be a hassle. -- So the ideal is as minimum as it can be. If the browser is not up-to-date you need to compromise look & feel on the altar of efficiency.